# Android - How can I have my app always listening for a keyword?

Tags: java, android, service

My question is, How can I make my app always listening for a keyword, then make my app start an activity?

How does the app Open Mic+ do this? Can I do this with Bounded Services? If not how can I get this code to be running in the background?

```
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Key pressed long!",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

I know automation apps like Tasker can do this, but how can I?
I have found **NO** solution. I am really considering decompiling Open Mic+ and looking at the source code to learn how to do it.

Thanks :)